# Oracle OpenScript can't parse a regular expression

Tags: regex, openscript

I have a wsdl file that I try to import to Oracle OpenScript webservices project.
It's importing but no methods are displayed. I found that the problem was a regular expression      `<xs:pattern value=".+T.+(Z|[+-].+)"/>`   I did a workaround but I don't understand why my initial regexp isn't good.
Could someone help me please?

PS  I'm trying to match a date value:  "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"

Comment: date value "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"

Comment: I also tested it with an online regex tester and I was fine but not good for OpenScript :(  I've replaced this line <xs:pattern value=".+T.+(Z|[+-].+)"/>  with  <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z"/> but still wondering why it doesn't like the initial regex :(

Comment: Tried it now, OpenScript is not parsing it

Comment: Then probably it has different format i guess